# Google Charts not displaying label outside of bar when bar is too small

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'd like my Google Bar Chart to display the bar label outside of the bar when the label is too large to fit inside. It looks like this is supposed to be the default behavior, but my charts aren't working that way. Here's a screenshot of the issue when the code is rendered. You can see this issue in question in rows 2,3,5,7 and 8.

[image: Bar Labels not outside of bar]

Here's my code:

```
// START Disease Resistance
function disease() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Disease', 'Resistance Rating', { role: 'annotation'}, { role: 'style'}, { role: 'tooltip'}],

    ['Barley Yellow Dwarf', 5, '5', '#221f72', 'Barley Yellow Dwarf | Resistance Rating: 5'], // Resistance rating is calculated by subracting the value from 10
    ['Fusarium Head Blight', 1, '9', '#221f72', 'Fusarium Head Blight | Resistance Rating: 9'],
    ['Hessian Fly', 1, '9', '#221f72', 'Hessian Fly | Resistance Rating: 9'],
    ['Leaf Rust', 2, '8', '#221f72', 'Leaf Rust | Resistance Rating: 8'],
    ['Powdery Mildew', 1, '9', '#221f72', 'Powdery Mildew | Resistance Rating: 9'],
    ['Soil-Borne Mosaic', 4, '6', '#221f72', 'Soil-Borne Mosaic | Resistance Rating: 6'],
    ['Stem Rust', 1, '9', '#221f72', 'Stem Rust | Resistance Rating: 9'],
    ['Stripe Rust', 1, '9', '#221f72', 'Stripe Rust | Resistance Rating: 9'],
    ['Tan Spot', 5, '5', '#221f72', 'Tan Spot | Resistance Rating: 5'],
    ['Wheat Streak Mosaic', 5, '5', '#221f72', 'Wheat Streak Mosaic | Resistance Rating: 5'],

  ]);
  var paddingHeight = 80;
  var rowHeight = data.getNumberOfRows() * 80;
  var chartHeight = rowHeight + paddingHeight;

  var options = {
      'backgroundColor': 'transparent',
    annotations: {textStyle: {fontSize: 16, fontName: 'Source Sans Pro'}},
    legend: { position: 'none'},
    height: chartHeight,
    colors: ['#F4AA00'],
    chartArea: {
      width: '100%',
      height: rowHeight
    },
    hAxis: {
        ticks: [{v:1, f:'9'}, {v:2, f:'8'}, {v:3, f:'7'}, {v:4, f:'6'}, {v:5, f:'5'}, {v:6, f:'4'}, {v:7, f:'3'}, {v:8, f:'2'}, {v:9, f:'1'}, {v:10, f:'0'}],
      title: '7-9 Susceptible | 4-6 Intermediate | 1-3 Resistant',
        viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10
    },
      minValue: 0,
      textStyle: {
        fontName: 'Source Sans Pro',
          bold: true,
        fontSize: 12,
        color: '#4d4d4d'
      },
      titleTextStyle: {
        fontName: 'Source Sans Pro',
          bold: true,
        fontSize: 14,
        color: '#4d4d4d'
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
        textPosition: 'in',
      title: 'Disease',
      textStyle: {
        fontName: 'Source Sans Pro',
          fontSize: 14,
        bold: false,
        color: '#fff'
      },
      titleTextStyle: {
        fontName: 'Source Sans Pro',
          fontSize: 14,
        bold: true,
        color: '#848484'
      }
    }
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('disease'));
  chart.draw(data, options);

    // redraw charts responsively
    (function($) {
        function resizeCharts () {
        chart.draw(data, options);
        }
        $(window).resize(resizeCharts);
    })( jQuery );
}
// END Disease Resistance
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obviously, the following option does not work well...

```
vAxis.textPosition: 'in'
```

and the only other option that might suffice...

```
theme: 'maximized'
```

allows the text to overflow, out of the bar.
which means half the text will be on a blue background,
and the rest on a white background.
with an appropriate font color, this looks *ok*, but also overlaps the annotation.

the only other option I came up with is to add the label to the annotation.
and remove from the y-axis.

this produces the same result as above,
but prevents the overlap with the annotation.

and also causes one other issue.
the text is placed at the end of the bar,
instead of the start.
to correct, we can manually move the annotations when the chart's `'ready'` event fires.
but the chart will move them back, on any interactivity, such as "hover / mouseover".
thus, we must use a `MutationObserver` to keep them in place, at the start of the bar.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(disease);

function disease() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Disease', 'Resistance Rating', { role: 'annotation'}, { role: 'style'}, { role: 'tooltip'}],

    ['', 5, 'Barley Yellow Dwarf: 5', '#221f72', 'Barley Yellow Dwarf | Resistance Rating: 5'], // Resistance rating is calculated by subracting the value from 10
    ['', 1, 'Fusarium Head Blight: 9', '#221f72', 'Fusarium Head Blight | Resistance Rating: 9'],
    ['', 1, 'Hessian Fly: 9', '#221f72', 'Hessian Fly | Resistance Rating: 9'],
    ['', 2, 'Leaf Rust: 8', '#221f72', 'Leaf Rust | Resistance Rating: 8'],
    ['', 1, 'Powdery Mildew: 9', '#221f72', 'Powdery Mildew | Resistance Rating: 9'],
    ['', 4, 'Soil-Borne Mosaic: 6', '#221f72', 'Soil-Borne Mosaic | Resistance Rating: 6'],
    ['', 1, 'Stem Rust: 9', '#221f72', 'Stem Rust | Resistance Rating: 9'],
    ['', 1, 'Stripe Rust: 9', '#221f72', 'Stripe Rust | Resistance Rating: 9'],
    ['', 5, 'Tan Spot: 5', '#221f72', 'Tan Spot | Resistance Rating: 5'],
    ['', 5, 'Wheat Streak Mosaic: 5', '#221f72', 'Wheat Streak Mosaic | Resistance Rating: 5'],

  ]);
  var paddingHeight = 80;
  var rowHeight = data.getNumberOfRows() * 80;
  var chartHeight = rowHeight + paddingHeight;

  var options = {
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    annotations: {textStyle: {fontSize: 16, fontName: 'Source Sans Pro'}},
    legend: {position: 'none'},
    height: chartHeight,
    colors: ['#F4AA00'],
    chartArea: {
      width: '100%',
      height: rowHeight
    },
    hAxis: {
      ticks: [{v:1, f:'9'}, {v:2, f:'8'}, {v:3, f:'7'}, {v:4, f:'6'}, {v:5, f:'5'}, {v:6, f:'4'}, {v:7, f:'3'}, {v:8, f:'2'}, {v:9, f:'1'}, {v:10, f:'0'}],
      title: '7-9 Susceptible | 4-6 Intermediate | 1-3 Resistant',
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 10
      },
      minValue: 0,
      textStyle: {
        fontName: 'Source Sans Pro',
        bold: true,
        fontSize: 12,
        color: '#4d4d4d'
      },
      titleTextStyle: {
        fontName: 'Source Sans Pro',
        bold: true,
        fontSize: 14,
        color: '#4d4d4d'
      }
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Disease',
      textStyle: {
        fontName: 'Source Sans Pro',
        fontSize: 14,
        bold: false
      },
      titleTextStyle: {
        fontName: 'Source Sans Pro',
        fontSize: 14,
        bold: true,
        color: '#848484'
      }
    }
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('disease'));

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(moveAnnotations);
    observer.observe(chart.getContainer(), {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });

  function moveAnnotations() {
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var chartBounds = chartLayout.getChartAreaBoundingBox();
    var barBounds = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('bar#0#0');
    var labels = chart.getContainer().getElementsByTagName('text');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(labels, function(label, index) {
      if (label.getAttribute('font-size') === '16') {
        label.setAttribute('x', barBounds.left + chartBounds.left + 4);
        label.setAttribute('fill', 'magenta');
        label.setAttribute('text-anchor', 'start');
      }
    });
  }

  chart.draw(data, options);

    // redraw charts responsively
    (function($) {
        function resizeCharts () {
        chart.draw(data, options);
        }
        $(window).resize(resizeCharts);
    })( jQuery );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="disease"></div>
```

note: not recommending using `'magenta'` as the color,
but demonstrates the need for another color...

Comment: Updated to upvote @WhiteHat's original answer. See my revised code below implementing his annotation recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @WhiteHat, I appreciate the detailed reply. I ended up nesting the disease information in with the annotation:

```
['Disease', 'Resistance Rating', { role: 'annotation'}, { role: 'style'}, { role: 'tooltip'}],

    ['Barley Yellow Dwarf', 5, 'Barley Yellow Dwarf | 5', '#221f72', 'Barley Yellow Dwarf | Resistance Rating: 5'], // Resistance rating is calculated by subracting the value from 10
    ['Fusarium Head Blight', 1, 'Fusarium Head Blight | 9', '#221f72', 'Fusarium Head Blight | Resistance Rating: 9'],
    ['Hessian Fly', 1, 'Hessian Fly | 9', '#221f72', 'Hessian Fly | Resistance Rating: 9'],
    ['Leaf Rust', 2, 'Leaf Rust | 8', '#221f72', 'Leaf Rust | Resistance Rating: 8'],
    ['Powdery Mildew', 1, 'Powdery Mildew | 9', '#221f72', 'Powdery Mildew | Resistance Rating: 9'],
    ['Soil-Borne Mosaic', 4, 'Soil-Borne Mosaic | 6', '#221f72', 'Soil-Borne Mosaic | Resistance Rating: 6'],
    ['Stem Rust', 1, 'Stem Rust | 9', '#221f72', 'Stem Rust | Resistance Rating: 9'],
    ['Stripe Rust', 1, 'Stripe Rust | 9', '#221f72', 'Stripe Rust | Resistance Rating: 9'],
    ['Tan Spot', 5, 'Tan Spot | 5', '#221f72', 'Tan Spot | Resistance Rating: 5'],
    ['Wheat Streak Mosaic', 5, 'Wheat Streak Mosaic | 5', '#221f72', 'Wheat Streak Mosaic | Resistance Rating: 5'],
```

Then, I hid the VAxis using the existing textPosition 'none' property:

```
    vAxis: {
        textPosition: 'none',
      ...etc.
```

Final result looks like this:
[image: Fixed bar chart example]

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat, updated the page, referencing my final code for reference in the comments of your original post.